# Sending email to multiple users with different greetings?

Tags: python, email

I am creating a email script in python. I am able to send mail to multiple users, but i want it to be able to say "Hello Jordan" or what ever the name of the recipient is before the body of the message. I can show the code i have if that helps.

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from email_R import emailRecipients

recipients = emailRecipients
addr_from = 'emailexample@gmail.com'

smtp_user = 'emailexample@gmail.com'
smtp_pass = 'password'

try:
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    msg['From'] = addr_from
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test Email'

    text = "This is a hours reminder.\nText and html."
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>This is a hours reminder.</p>
            <p>Text and HTML</p>
        <body>
    </html>
    """

    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.set_debuglevel(True)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Comment: not only does it help, it's mandatory

Comment: "Before" the body is not possible. You need to customize each "Subject" header or customize the body per recipient. This is not a strictly Python issue, but this deals with the RFC822 and SMTP transport rules.

Comment: Please view the SO [how to ask[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) which includes providing a set of code which can be used to reproduce your issue. So yes please provide your code.

Comment: If the mail is being sent to multiple users at once then you won't be able to customize as email just doesn't work that way. If you are performing a loop and are creating a separate email for each recipient then you shouldn't have any issues also customizing the content of the email.

Comment: You are sending the same email to multiple users so the message will be the same to all users. If you really want to send custom message you will need to loop through `emailRecipients` and append the information to either the subject, text, or html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rebuild a mail and lake an SMTP send for each recipient. Here is what should work:

```
recipients = emailRecipients
addr_from = 'emailexample@gmail.com'

smtp_user = 'emailexample@gmail.com'
smtp_pass = 'password'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')

try:
    subject_tpl = 'Test Email for {}'
    text_tpl = "This is a hours reminder for {}.\nText and html."
    html_tpl = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>This is a hours reminder for {}.</p>
            <p>Text and HTML</p>
        <body>
    </html>
    """
    server.set_debuglevel(True)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)

    # Loop for each recipient
    for recipient in recipients:
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = subject_tpl.format(recipient)
        msg['To'] = recipient
        msg['From'] = addr_from
        part1 = MIMEText(text_tpl.format(recipient), 'plain')
        part2 = MIMEText(html_tpl.format(recipient), 'html')
        msg.attach(part1)
        msg.attach(part2)
        server.sendmail(msg['From'], (recipient,), msg.as_string())
finally:
    server.quit()
```